# Where does nanoc create my site on windows?

Tags: ruby, nanoc

http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/3-getting-started/

I type nanoc create_site tutorial using cmd command line within a folder. It says it created the site but I can't find it in current directory where I launch the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange. Are you sure you have the permission to write to that folder? Try creating a site on the desktop, I never had such an issue under Windows.

Comment: maybe i was drunk I didn't see it in the first place :)

Comment: @user310291: asking "are you completely sure?" seemed me to be almost insulting ;) Aaahh, don't you love it when the solution is *that* simple?